# I've hidden the navigation bar and the status bar, now the screen edge pan gesture to go back won't work, is this typical?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios8, uinavigationbar

I'm curious, if I set the navigationBar to `hidden`, and also hide the status bar, my view controller no longer responds to the screen edge gesture to pop the view controller.

Is this expected behaviour? I tried to set the `interactivePopGestureRecognizer` to enabled in `viewDidLoad` after I hide the navigation bar, but it still won't work.

Comment: Yes it's completely normal behavior.

Comment: @soulshined How do I counteract this then?

Comment: See my answer for review. Just add the gesture to your viewDidLoad and you're all set! Happy coding

Comment: Did my answer answer your question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:YES];<--doesn't remove pop gesture

[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];<-- disables pop gesture
```

Simply use the first option, and in your root controller's viewDidAppear method use:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:NO];
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you've done things right? I've put together an example that seems to work for me. All I did was make the `navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES` and `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES]`

**-edit-**

After closer inspection, it looks like there are two different properties on UINavigationController. There is `navigationBar` which is the UINavigationBar view, and there is `navigationBarHidden` which is a boolean. When you set `navigationBarHidden` to true, the swipe gesture stops working. But if you set that actual view to be hidden with `navigationBar.hidden` then the gesture still works. Check the Git repository for an example.

Comment: I'm hiding the status bar with the `preferStatusBarHidden` method on `UIViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple work around:

Link a swipe gesture method to your navigation back button. Make the current view controller the target of the gesture recognizer (self), with the selector popThisViewController. Then install the gesture recognizer into the view that the user will swipe on. Don't forget to add your go back action

**edit added swipe gesture for reference to other coders that don't know**

Cleaner code will look like this:

```
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(goBack:)];
    gesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    gesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];
}

-(IBAction)goBack:(id)sender {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: This is very different from iOS 7's pop gesture. For one it goes from only the edge of the screen, for two it's interactive.

Comment: This is very different from iOS 7's pop gesture and can easily be remedied by hiding the nav bar in another way